For acoustic analysis of speech, is it better to convert stereo to mono (e.g. in Praat function) or is it better to extract 1 channel?
The 2 channels are pretty much the same. Does converting stereo to mono differ from extracting 1 channel? Is one approach better than the other?
Thanks in advance!
